# how i can redirect to subdirectory without showing it in the url using the .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a directory `/store` i want to redirect `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/store` .. without showing the `/store` in the url.

Also i need when i click any product in the `/store` like `/store/product1.html`, i need to to go to `www.example.com/store/Product1.html` without showing `/store` in the url.

I tried this, it redirect to the /store but it still on the url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^store/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ store/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !^store/ /store%{REQUEST_URI}
```